# Optimizing usage of getStyleClass()

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So often I find myself in situation where I want fine control over a lot of nodes and I keep calling:

```
node.getStyleClass().add(String);
```

Problem with this is that it can lead to some crazy repetitions. Honestly I cant think of anything. Is there some sort of "switch" that automatically tells my programm: "Hey, make each node a unique class so that I can edit it". Im thinking isnt there some global switch for that?

Comment: I don't understand what the issue here is.  Why would you want to "make each node a unique class so that I can edit it"?  What does that even mean?  Edit what in what way and why?  Are you referring to CSS classes or java classes?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well actually I mean css classes. I find myself in a situation where I have to call getStyleClass() various times so that I can adjust the node in my css. For the sake of not doing all those function calls I wonder if there is a more optimized way.

Comment: *Is there some sort of "switch" that automatically tells my programm: "Hey, make each node a unique class so that I can edit it".* No and BTW it's certainly not the purpose of style **classes** to uniquely identify nodes. Furthermore what's the benefit of doing this? You'd need to write N css selectors in your css file to style N nodes and instead of identifying a node by it's style class, simply identifying it by itself would be better.

Comment: @fabian oh wait, do they have something like nth-of-type? If so then I wouldnt need that and I could do: VBox:nth-of-type(n) or VBox[0] etc.